# d3.js rainbow chart animation enhancements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I've created this arc chart. I'd like to animate the labels better, have them tween with the arc animations. I've placed the labels inside to avoid being covered up.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/201/)

[image]

```
var arcGenerator = {
radius: 100,
oldData: "",
init: function(data){
    var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
    this.oldData = this.setData(clone, false);
    this.setup(this.setData(data, true));           
},
update: function(data){
    var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);          
    this.animate(this.setData(data, true));         
    this.oldData = this.setData(clone, false);
},
animate: function(data){
    var that = this;

    var chart = d3.select(".arcchart");
    that.generateArcs(chart, data);
},  
setData: function(data, isSorted){

    var diameter = 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;

    var localData = new Array();

    var displacement = 0;
    var oldBatchLength = 0;

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {               
        var riseLevels = value.segments;
        var riseLevelCount = riseLevels.length;

        if(oldBatchLength !=undefined){             
            displacement+=oldBatchLength;
        }

        var arcBatchLength = 2*Math.PI;
        var arcPartition = arcBatchLength/riseLevelCount;

            $.each(riseLevels, function( ri, value ) {
                var startAngle = (ri*arcPartition);
                var endAngle = ((ri+1)*arcPartition);

                if(index!=0){
                    startAngle+=displacement;
                    endAngle+=displacement;
                }

                riseLevels[ri]["startAngle"] = startAngle;
                riseLevels[ri]["endAngle"] = endAngle;                  
            });

        oldBatchLength = arcBatchLength;

        localData.push(riseLevels);
    });

    var finalArray = new Array();

    $.each(localData, function(index, value) {
        $.each(localData[index], function(i, v) {
            finalArray.push(v);
        });
    });

    return finalArray;

},
generateArcs: function(chart, data){

    var that = this;

    //_arc paths

    //append previous value to it.          
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        if(that.oldData[index] != undefined){
            data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = that.oldData[index].endAngle;
        }
        else{
            data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = 0;
        }
    });     


    var arcpaths = that.arcpaths.selectAll("path")
            .data(data);

        arcpaths.enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", function(d, i){
                return d.machineType;
            })  
            .style("fill", function(d, i){
                return d.color;
            })
            .transition()
            .ease("elastic")
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);               

        arcpaths.transition()
            .ease("elastic")                    
            .style("fill", function(d, i){
                return d.color;
            })
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween("d",arcTween);

        arcpaths.exit().transition()
            .ease("bounce")
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween)
            .remove();

    function arcTween(b) {

        var prev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
        prev.endAngle = b.previousEndAngle;
        var i = d3.interpolate(prev, b);

        return function(t) {
            return that.getArc()(i(t));
        };
    }
    //_arc paths





     var r = that.radius - 50;
    var ir = that.radius + 90;

                //__labels  
                var labels = that.labels.selectAll("text")
                    .data(data);

                labels.enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")


                labels
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
                        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (ir+((r-ir)/2));
                        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (r + 20);
                    })
                    .attr("y", function(d) {
                        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
                        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (ir+((r-ir)/2));
                        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (r + 20);
                    })
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d.color; 
                    })
                    .each(function(d) {
                        var bbox = this.getBBox();
                        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
                        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
                        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
                    })
                    .transition()
                        .duration(300)

                labels
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)      

                labels.exit().remove();
                //__labels            




                //__pointers
            that.pointers.append("defs").append("marker")
                    .attr("id", "circ")
                    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                    .attr("refX", 3)
                    .attr("refY", 3)
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", 3)
                    .attr("cy", 3)
                    .attr("r", 3);

                var pointers = that.pointers.selectAll("path.pointer")
                    .data(data);

                pointers.enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("class", "pointer")
                    .style("fill", "none")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)");

                pointers
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
                            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
                        } else {
                            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
                        }
                    })
                    .transition()
                        .duration(300)

                pointers
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)      

                pointers.exit().remove();

                //__pointers



},
setup: function(data){      
    var chart = d3.select("#threshold").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("class", "chart")
            .attr("width", 420)
            .attr("height", 420)
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "arcchart")
                .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");




    this.arcpaths = chart.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "arcpaths");


    this.labels = chart.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "labels");


    this.pointers = chart.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "pointer");



    this.generateArcs(chart, data);     
},
getArc: function(){
    var that = this;

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(function(d, i){
                return that.radius;
            })
            .outerRadius(function(d){
                var maxHeight = 100;
                var ratio = (d.height/maxHeight * 100)+that.radius;
                return ratio;
            })
            .startAngle(function(d, i){
                return d.startAngle;
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i){
                return d.endAngle;
            });

    return arc;
}
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataCharts = [
            {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "segments": [
                            {
                                height: 10,
                                color: "grey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 40,
                                color: "darkgrey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 33,
                                color: "grey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 50,
                                color: "darkgrey"
                            },
                            {
                                height: 33,
                                color: "grey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 10,
                                color: "darkgrey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 50,
                                color: "grey"
                            },
                            {
                                height: 45,
                                color: "darkgrey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 10,
                                color: "grey"                           
                            },
                            {
                                height: 40,
                                color: "darkgrey"                           
                            }                           
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "segments": [
                            {
                                height: 50,
                                color: "red"
                            },
                            {
                                height: 100,
                                color: "yellow"                         
                            },
                            {
                                height: 10,
                                color: "green"                          
                            }                       
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }               
        ];

        var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, dataCharts);

        arcGenerator.init(clone[0].data);

        $(".testers a").on( "click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, dataCharts);

            var pos = $(this).parent("li").index();
            arcGenerator.update(clone[pos].data);           
        });

});
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/204/)?

Comment: Yes, that is it. May I ask what was changed?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts for this. First, the animation of the pointer lines. This is relatively easy and the only thing you're missing is that the `.transition()` is in the wrong place:

```
pointers
  .transition()
  .duration(300)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
// etc
```

The second part is the animation of the text labels. This is a bit more difficult because their computation includes some side effects that allow the correct computation of the pointer lines. This comes in two parts -- the computation of the position and the computation of the extent of the displayed text. With that in mind, the changes are relatively straightforward, we just need to make sure that those computations take place before the transition starts:

```
labels.text(function(d) {
  return d.color; 
}).each(function(d) {
  var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
  d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (ir+((r-ir)/2));
  d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (ir+((r-ir)/2));
  d.x = d.x || Math.cos(a) * (r + 20);
  d.y = d.y || Math.sin(a) * (r + 20);
  var bbox = this.getBBox();
  d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
  d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
  d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
})
```

First, the text itself is set. This is required to be able to use `.getBBox()` to determine its dimensions. Then, all the values required by the pointer paths are computed -- these bits of code were previously in the computation of the position of the text, but that's what we want to transition to so those values are set later (except for new text labels that don't have coordinates set).

All that remains now is to animate the change of coordinates of the text in the same way as before:

```
.transition()
.duration(300)
.attr("x", function(d) {
  var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
  return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (r + 20);
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
  var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
  return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (r + 20);
});
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/204/).